# CMD prompt - bat file - Taskkill command ignores start /wait

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here's my script in my bat file:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steamapps\common\F13game\"

Start F13theGameRemap.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\F13Game\SummerCamp\Binaries\Win64\"

Start /WAIT SummerCamp.exe

Start /WAIT Taskkill /f /im F13theGameRemap.exe

exit
```

All I want is to run the first program, then the 2nd.  When the 2nd program "summercamp.exe" exits, i want the first program "F13thegameremap.exe" to exit.

The way this script works now is that Taskkill immediately ignores the start /wait command of summercamp.exe and closes F13theGameRemap.exe immediately.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong in that taskkill ignores the /wait. SummerCamp.exe is the one returning control back to the batch immediately, some .exe files do that. So try to run SummerCamp.exe without start and if this doesn't help insert a supervising loop checking if the game is still running with TaskList.

Comment: I dont know what a supervising loop is.  I tried removing the Start /wait and it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Echo off
Cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steamapps\common\F13game\"

Start F13theGameRemap.exe

Cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\F13Game\SummerCamp\Binaries\Win64\"

Set "App2=SummerCamp.exe"
Start /WAIT %App2%

:loop
Timeout /t 1 >NUL
tasklist.exe /FI "ImageName eq %App2%" /NH |find /i "%App2%" >NUL && Goto :loop

Start /WAIT Taskkill /f /im F13theGameRemap.exe
```

The :loop will check with 1 second delay if `%App2%` aka `SummerCamp.exe` is still running.

Comment: SummerCamp.exe apparently exits after spawning the real process. Fortunately it uses the same executable, or at least one with the same name, so it works to poll for it in the task list. If it spawned a different executable, then this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: FYI, using `start /wait` isn't required for SummerCamp.exe or taskkill.exe. It's needed for finding an executable by its "App Paths" registry key, but in this case you're running from the working directory and `PATH`.